# map to drive on server with bat file

Tags: networking, batch

I have a web server that I want to map a drive to it. I want to do this in a .bat file. Pseudo ->

Check if a drive at an ip address has been mapped to a local drive. 
If it has then progress with a reference to the drive
If not map to a local drive and then progress with a reference to the drive

Is this possible and if so how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to check if a mapping exists if the same drive letter is always used, the `net use` command will simply fail if it is unsuccessful at remapping with a system error 85.

e.g:

```
net use x: \\10.1.2.3\Share
```

Comment: Consider adding /persistent:yes to the end of this net use command to make the drive mapping persistent across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the drive mapping exists, say w: by checking for the nul device on that drive. I would also suggest using server name in the net use command instead of as IP address.

```
if exist w:nul goto END
net use w: \\webserver\share /persistent:yes

:END
@echo continue on with batch file here
```

Comment: if exist, not if exists